# Synchronizing request calls in Node

Tags: node.js

I am using the standard 'request' module

https://www.npmjs.org/package/request

I am wondering- if I have two successive/sequential request calls like so:

```
request.post({...});`  //first request

request.get({...});` //second request
```

...how to do I synchronize so that the first request always completes before the second gets called (the first request is authentication, so definitely needs to happen first).

The only way I know how to do this is to nest them like this:

```
 request.post({
    url: teamsnapURL,
    json: {
        user: "the1mills@yahoo.com",
        password: "******"
    }
}, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    teamSnapToken = res.headers['x-teamsnap-token'];

    request.get({
        url: 'https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams',
        json: {
        },
        headers: {
            'x-teamsnap-token':teamSnapToken
        }
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else{
            console.log('body:',body)
        }

})
});
```

is there another way?

One way is to use the node convention to pass in the callback function "next" and call that if authentication works, and otherwise throw an error. I will see if I can figure that out and add that as an answer (this questions doesn't have just one answer).

Here is non-nested callback way, solved with passing a function as a parameter. This appears to be pretty standard to avoided heavily nested function calls.

```
var request = require('request');
var teamsnapURL = 'https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/authentication/login';

var teamSnapToken = null;

var makeGetRequest = function(){

    request.get({
        url: 'https://api.teamsnap.com/v2/teams',
        json: {

        },
        headers: {
            'x-teamsnap-token':teamSnapToken
        }
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else{
            console.log('body:',body)
        }

    });

};

var authPost = function(makeGetRequest){

    request.post({
        url: teamsnapURL,
        json: {

            user: "the1mills@yahoo.com",
            password: "*******"
        }
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        teamSnapToken = res.headers['x-teamsnap-token'];
        makeGetRequest();

})};

authPost(makeGetRequest);
```

although I have to say, this seems to be just a silly excuse to use functions as objects, because both functions are in the same file, so you could just call the other function by name without having it nested OR passed in as a parameter, whatevs.

Comment: I think this is also possible with promises, but I don't know enough about promises to write a good answer.

Comment: If you're interested, I did a talk on various async styles of programming in JS, covers a lot of the options. Video is here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Patterns-Practices-Symposium-Online/pattern-practices-symposium-2013/Embracing-Async-Programming

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty much it - you way you know that a request has completed is that the callback fires, so if you have something that must happen after the first request completes, you have to do it in the callback.

There are ways to make this look easier, but it's still fundamentally the same thing. For example, using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, something like this:

```
async.waterfall([
    function (done) {
        request.post(firstRequest, function (err, res, body) { done(err, res, body); });
    },
    function (done, res, body) {
        teamSnapToken = res.headers[...];
        request.get(second-request, function (err, res, body) { done(err, res, body); });
    }
    ],
    function (err, result) {
        // final callback here
    });
```

Comment: there has to be a way to synchronize, in Java you would use an object's monitor, using the synchronize keyword and the wait() and notify()/notifyAll() methods

Comment: Neat! I hadn't seen that one before. However, under the hood what it's doing is called "continuation passing style tranformation" - basically doing the callback stuff, and rewriting the code to make it look like a straight synchronous flow. Another example would be https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs. Java monitors work because it's multithreaded and it's ok to block a thread. Javascript is single-threaded and it's NOT ok to block the one and only thread to wait for something.

Comment: i see. i guess there's no way to create a new thread in node? i think there is

Comment: One other way is to use the node convention to pass in the callback function "next" and call that if authentication works, and otherwise throw an error. I will see if I can figure that out and add that as an answer

Comment: You can't throw an error from a callback and have it acted on. You have to return it as the first parameter to the callback. Otherwise the error gets thrown into the void - it will end up at the global unhandled exception handler, which is bad.